# How to convert below given array of objects to expected array of object output with specific keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**Given Object**

The array of objects is given to us as follows, we have to convert it to the expected array of objects.

```
    [
        {
          "tm_number": "9724084103",
          "tm_name": "PRADIP BHAI",
          "zsm_number": "9974252013",
          "zsm_name": "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
          "zbm_number": "1234567890",
          "zbm_name": "ARIF MALEK",
          "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
          "zone_name": "Surat",
          "circle_name": "Gujarat",
          "category": "Challenger"
        },
        {
          "tm_number": "9724084103",
          "tm_name": "PRADIP duplicate",
          "zsm_number": "9974252013",
          "zsm_name": "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
          "zbm_number": "1234567890",
          "zbm_name": "ARIF MALEK",
          "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
          "zone_name": "Surat",
          "circle_name": "Gujarat",
          "category": "Challenger"
        },
        {
          "tm_number": "9724084105",
          "tm_name": "PRADIP BHAI",
          "zsm_number": "9974252013",
          "zsm_name": "Jay Ambe Communicati",
          "zbm_number": "1234567890",
          "zbm_name": "ARIF MALEK",
          "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
          "zone_name": "Surat",
          "circle_name": "Gujarat",
          "category": "Challenger"
        },
        {
          "tm_number": "972484103",
          "tm_name": "SK BHAI",
          "zsm_number": "9974252013",
          "zsm_name": "Jay Ambe 2 Communicati",
          "zbm_number": "1234567890",
          "zbm_name": "ARIF MALEK",
          "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
          "zone_name": "Surat",
          "circle_name": "Gujarat",
          "category": "Challenger"
        },
        {
          "tm_number": "972484103",
          "tm_name": "SK BHAI",
          "zsm_number": "9974252013",
          "zsm_name": "Jay Ambe 3 Communicati",
          "zbm_number": "1234567890",
          "zbm_name": "ARIF MALEK",
          "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
          "zone_name": "Surat",
          "circle_name": "Gujarat",
          "category": "Challenger"
        }
    ]
```

**Expected Object Output**

```
    [
      {
        "9724084103": [
          {
            "tm_name": "PRADIP BHAI",
            "zsm_number": "9974252013",
            "zsm_name": "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
            "zbm_number": "1234567890",
            "zbm_name": "ARIF MALEK",
            "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
            "zone_name": "Surat",
            "circle_name": "Gujarat",
            "category": "Challenger"
          },
          {
            "tm_name": "PRADIP duplicate",
            "zsm_number": "9974252013",
            "zsm_name": "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
            "zbm_number": "1234567890",
            "zbm_name": "ARIF MALEK",
            "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
            "zone_name": "Surat",
            "circle_name": "Gujarat",
            "category": "Challenger"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "9724084105": [
          {
            "tm_number": "9724084105",
            "tm_name": "PRADIP BHAI",
            "zsm_number": "9974252013",
            "zsm_name": "Jay Ambe Communicati",
            "zbm_number": "1234567890",
            "zbm_name": "ARIF MALEK",
            "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
            "zone_name": "Surat",
            "circle_name": "Gujarat",
            "category": "Challenger"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "972484103": [
          {
            "tm_name": "SK BHAI",
            "zsm_number": "9974252013",
            "zsm_name": "Jay Ambe 2 Communicati",
            "zbm_number": "1234567890",
            "zbm_name": "ARIF MALEK",
            "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
            "zone_name": "Surat",
            "circle_name": "Gujarat",
            "category": "Challenger"
          },
          {
            "tm_name": "SK BHAI",
            "zsm_number": "9974252013",
            "zsm_name": "Jay Ambe 3 Communicati",
            "zbm_number": "1234567890",
            "zbm_name": "ARIF MALEK",
            "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
            "zone_name": "Surat",
            "circle_name": "Gujarat",
            "category": "Challenger"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

*NOTE:*

> keys will be dynamic so manage your program accordingly

Below is the approach I used, but not getting the expected output as above. Could you please efficient way of doing this?

```js
const data = [
{
    tm_number: "9724084103",
    tm_name: "PRADIP BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "9724084103",
    tm_name: "PRADIP duplicate",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "9724084105",
    tm_name: "PRADIP BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "972484103",
    tm_name: "SK BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe 2 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "972484103",
    tm_name: "SK BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe 3 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
];

function groupId(data) {
  let obj = {};
  const mydata = data.map((item) => {
    if (obj[item.tm_number]) {
      obj[item.tm_number].push(item);
    } else {
      obj[item.tm_number] = [item];
    }

    return obj;
  });

  console.log(mydata);
}

groupId(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), not `map`, which is returning multiple copies of `obj` into your result. Then you can split the result object into an array of objects using `map`:

```js
const data = [{
    tm_number: "9724084103",
    tm_name: "PRADIP BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "9724084103",
    tm_name: "PRADIP duplicate",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "9724084105",
    tm_name: "PRADIP BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "972484103",
    tm_name: "SK BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe 2 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "972484103",
    tm_name: "SK BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe 3 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
];

function groupId(data) {
  const mydata = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
    if (obj[item.tm_number]) {
      obj[item.tm_number].push(item);
    } else {
      obj[item.tm_number] = [item];
    }
    return obj;
  }, {});
  return Object.entries(mydata).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k] : v }));
}

console.log(groupId(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top 0 }
```

Comment: @MurtazaKhachrodwala apologies for not getting the format right; I should have paid more attention. I've updated my answer to give the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong comprehension of `map` function, but the logic of callback in your map function is correct.

Here is explanation of `Array.map` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

In your original solution, `mydata` isn't the answer, variable `obj` does.
Try to print `obj` variable in your console and you'll see what I'm talking about.

I think the right way to solve this problem is use `forEach` or just simple `for loop`. There's no need to make the problem complicated, just keep it simple.

```js
const data = [{
    tm_number: "9724084103",
    tm_name: "PRADIP BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "9724084103",
    tm_name: "PRADIP duplicate",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "9724084105",
    tm_name: "PRADIP BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "972484103",
    tm_name: "SK BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe 2 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "972484103",
    tm_name: "SK BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe 3 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
];

function groupId(data) {
  let obj = {};

  data.forEach(item => {
    if (obj[item.tm_number]) {
      obj[item.tm_number].push(item);
    } else {
      obj[item.tm_number] = [item];
    }
  });

  return [obj];
}
  
console.log(groupId(data));
```

### UPDATE

Since I misread your expected output, I've updated my answer below, have a look!

```js
const data = [
  {
    tm_number: "9724084103",
    tm_name: "PRADIP BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "9724084103",
    tm_name: "PRADIP duplicate",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe1 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "9724084105",
    tm_name: "PRADIP BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "972484103",
    tm_name: "SK BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe 2 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
  {
    tm_number: "972484103",
    tm_name: "SK BHAI",
    zsm_number: "9974252013",
    zsm_name: "Jay Ambe 3 Communicati",
    zbm_number: "1234567890",
    zbm_name: "ARIF MALEK",
    "ceo/sales_head/marketing_head_number": "9898049452",
    zone_name: "Surat",
    circle_name: "Gujarat",
    category: "Challenger",
  },
];

function groupId(data) {
  let obj = {},
    result = [];

  data.forEach((e) => {
    if (obj[e.tm_number]) {
      obj[e.tm_number].push(e);
    } else {
      obj[e.tm_number] = [e];
    }
  });

  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    result.push({ [keys[i]]: obj[keys[i]] });
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(groupId(data));
```

Comment: `reduce` I think is more traditional for grouping but this definitely does the job too.

Comment: @Nick Agree! However, consider that lots of people don't know how to use `reduce` correctly. And also, you've already provided the excellent `reduce` method for this question, so I just want to gave another solution for them.

Comment: Absolutely - that's why I upvoted.

Comment: @Kurt @Nick Agreed with your solution with `reduce` and `forEach` but the thing is output still not matching with the expected output. In the expected output, each key is in a different obj, and then those objects are in the array. Please have a look.

Comment: @MurtazaKhachrodwala I've updated my answer to your expected output.